# Spring Web Flow and HDIV integration

Tags: spring-webflow, hdiv

I'd like to use spring web flow with HDIV. Is this possible out of the box, with only configuration? Or I have to write some swf flowhandlers, listeners? I could not find any information on this. Older version of hdiv (2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.1.0RC1) contain module for web flow with classes like FlowHandlerAdapterHDIV, but it is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDIV 2.0.4 is the last version that support Spring Webflow.
Supported Spring Webflow version is 1.0.5 and there is an example app in the download zip called 'hdiv-web-webflow-1.0.5'.

Newer versions of Webflow are not maintained by HDIV.
If you want to build it yourself, you can look in this code : https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/pull/2/